# Changing background Image with onMouseOver(this) displays white for a second. How to solve the bug?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, web

I'm using `onmouseover(this)` to change background image with javascript. "this" is a parameter to retrieve the id of the element. Id is the image's name.

I created circled bubbles through html with the help of php loop. Each bubble is shown as an image and its also an input for a form. Each time i move the mouse over a bubble the page `backgroundImage` is supposed to change to a specific image. I also transform the scale and opacity of each bubble but i don't believe it has anything to do with this.

**The bug**

Refreshing the page, the first 2 times i move the mouse over a bubble it bugs and show white background for about a second. After these first 2 times it works fine. Refreshing will make the bug occur again. I can't understand why is this bug happening and how to solve it.

**HTML**

```
<!-- -----Bubbles (ROW/COL/TABLE/PHP)-----                                     -->
    <form action="/searches/se_racestandingsround" method="post">@csrf                                    
        <div class="row mt-5 mr-5 ml-5">
            <?php for($i=2021; $i>=1950; $i--){ ?>
                <div class="col-3 d-flex flex-column align-items-center mb-3 mt-5">
                    <div class="w-50 mb-5 rounded-circle" style="height: 150px;">
                        <div class="bg-dark w-100 h-100 mb-5 border rounded-circle" id="<?php echo $i ?>" onmouseover="onMouseOver(this)" onmouseout="onMouseOut(this)">
                            <input class="round" type="hidden" name="round" id="<?php echo $i+100 ?>" value="">
                            <input class="rnd" type="hidden" name="rnd" id="<?php echo $i+200 ?>" value="">
                            <button style="object-fit:cover" class="w-100 h-100 border rounded-circle"><img src='/imgs/jpg/years/<?php echo $i ?>.jpg' style="object-fit:cover" class="w-100 h-100 border rounded-circle"></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function onMouseOver(year){
        var element = document.getElementById('conf');
        var curYear = year.id; 

        for(y=2021; y>=1950; y--){
            document.getElementById(y+100).value = curYear;
            document.getElementById(y+200).value = currentNumOfRounds;
        }
        
  
        element.style.backgroundImage = "url('/imgs/jpg/yearswinner/"+curYear+".jpg')";
        for(i=2021; i>=1950; i--){
            if(i==curYear){
                document.getElementById(i).style.opacity = "1";
                document.getElementById(i).style.transition = "transform .2s";
                document.getElementById(i).style.transform = "scale(1.1)";
            }else{
                document.getElementById(i).style.opacity = "0.5";
                document.getElementById(i).style.transition = "transform .2s";
                document.getElementById(i).style.transform = "scale(0.9)";
            }          
        }     
    }
```

Comment: It may has to do with the page not finish loading. What could i do about that?

Answer (score 0):

When you change the background image with this line of code, you're causing the page to download the image.

```js
element.style.backgroundImage = "url('/imgs/jpg/yearswinner/"+curYear+".jpg')";
```

Because your connection to the server might not be the quickest, it's taking a while for the browser to download the image, and is displaying your `#conf` element with a partially downloaded image in it. This is why it looks white the first one or two times you mouse over a bubble.

What you really should be doing is loading everything on page-load and hiding it until you want it displayed, with something like this:

```html
<img src='/imgs/jpg/yearswinner/whateveryear.jpg' id='winner-whateveryear' style='display:none'>
```

*NB: the inline styles here are just an example, use something else*

Then in your `onMouseOver()` function, instead of changing a background image of your `#conf` element, use

```js
document.getElementById("winner-whateveryear").style.display = "block";
```